# UK channels missing since re tune

Tags: tv-antenna

Got an issue with 1 of our TVs since Freeview changed around and everyone had to re tune.

I have 3 TVs in the house all from same aerial and been working since, then had to retune them all due to Freeview changes at start of march and all went well apart from the living room TV. It gets bbc1 and 2 but skips nearly all channels below 100. HD  works fine but missing some others here and there.

I've plugged it into the same point as the kitchen TV but still doesn't re tune. I've tried to reinitialize the channels many times on different wall points but doesn't get them, even though the other TVs do.

Any ideas, the TV in question is a Samsung UE50NU7020K

Regards
Liam

Comment: how is this a home improvement question? ... it is a question about the use of a device

Comment: make sure you're looking at "all channels" and not just your favorites.

Comment: Retuning is needed when the stations change what frequency they're broadcasting on.  It may be that you need a different/better (higher gain) antenna.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with home improvement.

Comment: There's a 50:50 chance the person needs to install a wideband aerial on their house rather than it being a TV usability issue. Is that off topic here?

Comment: I just couldn't see what else this would sit under. Found some other Freeview related questions on here. The odd thing about changing aerials is that the other (ironically older) TVs still get all channels even on same cable and outlet

Answer (score 1):

Freeview retunes can change the frequency, power and other technical characteristics of the digital signal. This can cause problems for some receivers and not others due to differences in software, sensitivity and the quality of the signal on that cable.

Historically many TV aerials were designed to favour a narrow frequency band specific to each region. This is called a grouped aerial. If you have one of these then the retune might have pushed some channels outside of this band and the TV might be getting a weak signal for the new frequencies.

Ultimately you might need to consult a local aerial fitter who will be familiar with local issues and their solutions. This might mean changing your aerial type or adding an amplifier or filters.

Bear in mind that the problem might be temporary. Some retunes are done in two phases. You might be in an interim period with less than ideal conditions and will have another retune in a few weeks or months to implement the longer term configuration.

I suggest:

- Check the antenna cable is not kinked or damaged for the best signal strength.
- Check the antenna cable coax connector is wired correctly for the best signal strength. Look on the web for guides.
- Perform a software update on your TV, either over the air or from the internet. In the past I fixed a severe tuning problem for someone with a receiver software update.
- Some TVs let you manually enter the frequency for each channel multiplex. Check your TV's user guide and use Google to look up the frequencies you need to input for your region. After this, you might need to disable auto-retune.
- You might be able to find a pattern to the channels that are missing. Look at the following website and half way down the page choose the link for your region. You should be able to find a list of frequency number changes, recommended aerial types and affected multiplexes (e.g. PSB2). Use Google to find the channels that are in each multiplex.  https://www.freeview.co.uk/corporate/platform-management/700mhz-clearance/clearance-events-2020
- Check if your area is at risk of interference from mobile phone cells: https://at800.tv/im-sure-received-postcard/
- Contact Samsung support.
- Replace your home's TV aerial with a wideband model if your region requires it. This can be done DIY, but I would ask a professional to specify and fit it, especially if the aerial is high up on the house as is the norm in the UK.